# R get max, keyed by another function (like in Python)

Tags: r, max

In Python, we can do something like

```
max(stuff, key=lambda x: abs(x.foo))
```

Which would return the element of `stuff` which has the member `foo` with the highest absolute value.

How would I do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

so i suppose stuff must be a list of vectors (or lists) with named elements, something like this:

```
stuff <- list( first = c(bang=1, qux = 2, foo = 3),
               second = c(bang=6, qux = 0, foo= 100),
               third = c(bang = 1, qux = 7, foo = 0))
```

you can get the element "foo" using sapply:

```
sapply(stuff, function(.) .['foo'])
```

... then find the maximum of it:

```
which.max(sapply(stuff, function(.) .['foo']))
```

... and then use it to index your list:

```
stuff[which.max(sapply(stuff, function(.) .['foo']))]
```

or with magrittr:

```
stuff %>% {.[sapply(., "[", "foo") %>% which.max]}
```